# If two maps are homotopic, are the images homotopy equivalent?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

My question is;

If two continuous maps $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ are homotopic, are the images $Im(f),Im(g)$ homotopy equivalent?

Clearly, the converse is false.

If it is false, is there any condition to be true?
(Such as $f$ or $g$ to be injective)

Comment: Consider the embedding $f$ of a null-homotopic circle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$X=Y=D^2$(closed 2-disc). Since $D^2$ is contractible, any map $f:D^2\to D^2$ is homotopic to constant map. Now consider $g_1:D^2\to D^2$ be a constant map and consider a surjective map $g:D^2\to S^1$ and define $g_2= i\circ g:D^2\to D^2$ where $i$ define the inclusion map of $S^1$ into $D^2$. Then image of $g_1$ is a point and image of $g_2$ is circle which are no thomotopically equivalnet.

Comment: Good example.  Note that both of these maps fail to be injective.  I think you could make the same argument taking $g_1$ to be the identity map, which gets around this for one of the maps;  but I suspect that you can't map $D^2$ bijectively to any space that is deformation-retractable to $S^1$.

Comment: Is it possible to $g:D^2\rightarrow S^1$ be surjective?
I think that makes $g$ be a retraction from $D^2$ to $S^1$.

Comment: @wooa0923 why not? can you think of a surjective map from $D^2$ onto an closed interval...and then can you define a surective map from closed interval onto $S^1$?

Comment: @Anubhav How about $H_1(S^1)\rightarrow H_1(D^2) \rightarrow H_1(S^1)$

Comment: @wooa0923 what are you saying? what is the meaning of considering homology?

Comment: Saying $i:S^1\rightarrow D^2$ to be embedding and $r:D^2\rightarrow S^1$ to be retraction, then $r\circ i=id$ implies $r_*\circ i_*=id_*$ in homology. But I think that cannot happen in upper sequence since the first homology of disk is zero.

Comment: @wooa0923 but I am not taking $g$ as retraction, it is just a surjective map, not any map is retraction.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I've seen wrong. Thank you for correcting :)

Comment: @wooa0923 any more doubt?